# How to stop XCode replacing system commands in run script phase?

Tags: xcode, bash, sdk, command

My situation:
OSX 10.9 + Xcode 4.6.3 + run script phase + script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/svn --version
ls -la /usr/bin/svn
exit 1
```

I receive the outputs:

```
svn, version 1.6.18 (r1303927)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14224 26 oct 05:08 /usr/bin/svn
```

This is unbelievable. The size and date of the real file correspond with v1.7.10 (which is really placed at the path `/usr/bin/svn`) but calling this file from within XCode will call the `/Application/Xcode463.app/Content/Developer/usr/bin/svn` command!

How can I prevent this? How can I call my default `/usr/bin/svn` command?
How is it possible to do hidden replacement of one command with another without replacing the real file?

Comment: I do many drastic things but I will not recommend you to do it..

take a backup of /usr/bin/svn and keep it safe somewhere..

now delete the /usr/bin/svn and create a new softlink say /usr/bin/svn will invoke that /Application/Xcode463.app/Content/Developer/usr/bin/svn ...

Just in case this doesnt work you can replace backup file in its original  place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is that `/usr/bin/svn` is a link to the `xcrun` wrapper. Command to see it:

```
nm /usr/bin/svn
```

So root cause of issue is next command:

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

in the run script phase will print current Xcode instead of system default Xcode.